# Obrigar quem deu downvote a comentar o motivo

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

É possível adicionar uma funcionalidade que o obriga o usuário quando der **downvote** explicar o motivo em um comentário? Hoje tive 2 **downvotes** sem motivo um em cada pergunta ([Dividir coluna em múltiplas tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56630/dividir-coluna-em-m%C3%BAltiplas-tabelas) / [Recursividade em CUDA e OpenCL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65600/recursividade-em-cuda-e-opencl)) cada pergunta anteriormente tinha **upvotes**, indaguei nos comentários qual o motivo mas o dono do downvote não comentou, a meu ver não há nada de errado com estas perguntas, outras situações que já ocorreram foram:

- Alguém responde uma pergunta que você respondeu e estranhamente todas as outras respostas recebem downvote.
- O autor marcar uma resposta como válida e em seguida todas as utras recebem downvotes.

Em abas as situações notei que todas respostas que obtiveram um downvote solucionavam o problemas ou eram passiveis de solucionar.

Não estou reclamando por causa do -2 de reputação mas sim pelo histórico de pontuação que fica na pergunta / resposta.

Extra: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura) O que há de errado nesta questão que foi a primeira a ter 100 upvotes para que ela recebe-se 2 downvotes?

Já recebi downvotes de membros que explicaram o motivo (não estou reclamando destes casos) e nestes casos geraram boas discussões, descobri coisas que não sabia e pude reformular minha resposta com novo conteúdo.

Comment: Relacionado [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/652/91)

Comment: E não vai postar o motivo do downvote?

Comment: A esperança já foi lançada há tempo, veja http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2259/3082 mas já adianto, sem sucesso kkk.

Comment: [Não dei downvote](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QeLSY.png) @ricardo.

Comment: -1 (que no meta, em pedidos de novo recurso, quer dizer "discordo")

Comment: Até que enfim alguém explicou o motivo do downvote.

Comment: As vezes recebeu downvote porque foi contemplado por usuário novo que está querendo a medalha "Crítico".

Comment: -1 Acho que "sem motivo" não existe. A pessoa tinha motivo sim, o negócio é que *nunca, jamais*, ninguém vai saber qual é. A não ser que ela se manifeste, tipo acabo de fazer. Obrigar a manifestar vai contra a liberdade do voto. Aos 5k já é hora de ter o couro mais curtido :P

Comment: @brasofilo ainda és vivo?

Comment: @ricardo -1 se esse recurso existisse ninguém dava downvote por ter de explicar o porquê.

Comment: @JorgeB., dizem que quem é vivo sempre desaparece :)

Comment: Também dei -1 aqui (pelo mimimi), mas dei +1 nas duas perguntas. Não vi nada de errado, e também não entendi a razão dos dowvotes nelas, mas como já disseram aí, vc já devia estar com o coro mais duro. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não sei o que se passa na cabeça de cada usuário que votou negativo e nem o motivo que levou a estes votos, mas posso citar os possíveis "problemas" das perguntas:

1. [Dividir coluna em múltiplas tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56630/3635)

   O motivo me parece que é por não especificar o tipo de **banco**, como sendo mysql, PostgreSQL, sqlserver e o **motor** usado neste banco (como innoDB).
2. [Recursividade em CUDA e OpenCL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65600/3635)

   Está pergunta é bem ampla ao meu ver, eu não daria um voto negativo, no entanto se eu tive-se visto ela antes da resposta eu teria solicitado mais detalhes com um comentário tipo "o que exatamente quer fazer" e talvez teria pedido pra fechar.

No momento só irei adicionar um comentário pedindo mais detalhes -- *note que está é minha opinião*.

3. [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/3635)

   A mesma coisa do item "2", é bem ampla, se eu participasse do *SOpt* talvez teria solicitado o fechamento, no entanto o autor parece que criou está pergunta para agregar conteúdo ao site e provavelmente ele já tinha uma noção ou até mesmo sabia a resposta e claramente está pergunta seria feita uma hora ou outra. Os dois votos negativos foram porque provavelmente este dois usuários não entenderam o motivo de agregar conteúdo (estou passando por uma situação semelhante no Portuguese.SE :( )

Note que isto provavelmente é uma opinião pessoal destas pessoas e o SOpt abre umas brechas para perguntas mais amplas as vezes, não quer dizer que são ruins, apenas amplas ou necessitam de detalhes, ou até mesmo são para servirem de fonte posteriormente, infelizmente alguns usuários não entendem isto.

Mesmo editando as suas perguntas, não quer dizer que eles vão remover os votos negativos, eles ainda podem discordar de algo, ou até mesmo esquecer que votaram. Então não se importe muito com isto.

**Nota:** Edite as suas perguntas e eu jogo um +1 pra cada :)

---

### Novo recurso

Discordo desta obrigatoriedade, isto faria as pessoas terem medo de votar negativamente pela possibilidade de serem "perseguidas" (não estou dizendo que acontece, mas as pessoas temem isto).

Eu prefiro uma ferramenta que avise o usuário que votou "negativamente" e "positivamente" em uma postagem saber se houve edição, seria um  meio da pessoa poder saber se o voto dela é justificado para edição, se não remove o voto (sendo down ou up) ou muda (de down para up ou vice-versa).

Assim como votos negativos, aonde o autor (ou quem editou) melhora a pergunta/resposta e quem votou pode analisar se aquele voto negativo é merecido ainda.

Comment: Editarei, mas veja bem eu já tive downvotes (se não me falha a memoria foram o VitorStafusa e OnoSendai) por conteúdo de resposta insuficiente ambos comentaram o motivo e sinceramente só tive a agradecer o que o OnoSendai comentou me fez mudar um projeto e o o que o VitorStafusa comentou e discutimos no chat me fez ter novos conhecimentos sobre modificadores.

Comment: Outro ponto ambos os downvotes foram dados hoje sendo que a pergunta  Dividir coluna em múltiplas tabelas foi feita a mais de 3 meses e já esta respondida, fora os outros dois pontos que já reparei e citei na minha pergunta.

Comment: @ricardo eu tenho uma pergunta no SOen que tinha 4 meses e depois destes 4 meses eu recebi 2 votos negativos em dois dias seguidos (fiquei com -2). Isto ocorre devido a pessoa estar pesquisando algo semelhante, no entanto ela achar que a sua pergunta tem problemas, não me parece algo arbitrário. Depois eu entendi os votos negativos dela, foram porque alguns no SOen acham que perguntas sobre php+apache são mais voltadas ao server.SE, no entanto recebi +8 votos positivos na mesma pergunta, isto quer dizer que nem todos tem a mesma opinião.

Comment: Eu ainda fico ressabiado pois a pergunta sobre banco de dados era sobre modelagem, outro ponto são os downvotes em respostas que citei. mas entendo seu ponto de vista

Comment: @ricardo pode ser que você tenha razão e alguém está lhe "perseguindo" (já fui perseguido duas vezes kk -- era um cara bem sem noção)... No entanto a "modelagem" pode até seguir a mesma logica desenhada, mas pode ser que haja dois tipos de modelagens para tecnologias diferentes e a sua pergunta e resposta não ajudou as "pessoas". Ricardo se notar alguma perseguição realmente acho que deveria contactar um moderador, mas acho que ainda não é o momento. No entanto sobre o novo recurso eu não acho que forçar a justificativa "seja algo" legal.

Comment: @ricardo veja isto http://stackoverflow.com/q/30021456/1518921 ... no dia fiquei revoltado ganhei +5 ao longo dos 3/4 meses descobri a resposta sozinho e postei, dois dias depois tinha -2, entrei no meta.so perguntando aonde poderia melhorar, ganhei +13 (total +18) (prováveis opiniões que apoiavam o tipo de pergunta) e depois -3 (total -5). Então parei de "brigar" lá, pois percebi que cada um vê a coisa de uma maneira :( infelizmente. kk -- não vou esquecer seus pontos amigo!

Comment: Ofereci um UpVote para a resposta. Como ainda não existe o campo para comentar, insiro aqui.