# Ao Negativar Perguntas e/ou Respostas, Sugerir a inclusão de um comentário

Tags: debate

Ao negativar uma pergunta ou uma respostas, não deveria ser obrigatório o usuário informar o motivo da negativação? 
Acredito que assim estaríamos instruindo o autor do seu devido erro e permitindo assim a evolução de toda a comunidade.
O que acham?

**Complementando:**

Minha questão é: Como podemos melhorar a comunidade, instruindo melhor seus membros?

Ao negativar apenas, quem recebeu muitas vezes não sabe o porque.

Se existe o 'medo' de perseguição ou coisa do tipo, o comentário relacionado ao voto negativo poderia ser anônimo.

Outra opção poderia ser, ao clicar no botão down, poderia abrir uma 'janela' para o usuário incluir seu comentário (dando um foco na importância do comentário), e se for o caso, ainda assim dar a opção dele pular esta etapa.

Hoje ao negativar, quem a faz perde 1 ponto de reputação. E se a pessoa ao negativar e efetuar um comentário, não perdesse este ponto? Isso não incentivaria termos mais comentários?

Comment: Relacionada: [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/28595)

Comment: Relacionada²: [Respostas negativadas mas sem explicação do motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4540/28595)

Comment: Já tiveram inúmeras discussões sobre isso, e em nenhuma isso foi visto como uma boa solução. Vale a pena você da uma olhada nestes links sobre o tema, la tem muitos motivos para que isso nunca seja aceito na comunidade.

Comment: @diegofm eu olhei as outras questões e me parecem estar muito voltadas a negativação de respostas e não na melhoria do conteúdo da comunidade, por isso abri um novo tópico. Temo que achar maneira de incentivar os comentários e lembrar os membros como os comentários são importantes.

Comment: E você acha que obrigando é a melhor solução? O sistema já sugere através de um tooltip que quem votou deixe um comentário, fica a cargo da pessoa comentar. Obrigar nunca será a melhor opção. Além do mais, boas respostas negativadas injustamente geralmente recebem o dobro de votos positivos, isso ajuda a equilibrar as coisas e evitar usuarios com más itenções. E sempre que desconfiar de perseguição, a moderação pode ser acionada para investigar.

Comment: @diegofm veja que editei o tópico e complementei com outras opções. Entendo a não obrigatoriedade, mas apenas este tooltip não me parece ser o suficiente, visto que não está dando certo.

Comment: Uma duvida, baseado em que você afirma que `não está dando certo`?

Comment: Pelo numero de questões e/ou respostas negativadas vs o numero de comentários que cada uma tem. Entenda que não estou nem me referindo a uma questão especifica e não estou reclamando de perseguição(não é este caso), mas já vi questões de outras pessoas negativadas e como eu não entendi o porque, imagino que quem fez a pergunta também ficou em duvida. E o que você acha das outra sugestões que inclui no tópico?

Comment: Acho que você está equivocado, o número de votos positivos é imensamente superior aos negativos, não creio que haja problema nisso. A SE não vai implementar comentário anônimo, duvido muito, há inúmeros recursos mais úteis sugeridos aqui no meta e nenhum foi pra frente. O que nos resta é se adaptar ao sistema e reportar casos suspeitos, ao menos nossa moderação é bastante ativa disposta a ajudar.

Comment: Concordo que existem funcionalidades mais interessantes no meta e o SE ainda (se é que vão) não implementaram, mas isso não deveria impedir-nos de fazer novas sugestões não é verdade? E quanto a possibilidade de não subtrair 1 ponto caso se inclua um comentário? Que outras opções poderíamos ter para incentivar os comentários? Acredito que no geral os votos positivos possam se superar, mas para aquela pessoa que fez uma pergunta, teve a mesma negativada e não teve informação, como poderia minimizar estas ocorrências?

Comment: Veja esta questão por exemplo. Recebeu 3 votos negativos (ou seja 3 pessoas diferentes) mas apenas vc @diegofm está comentando. E tenho certeza que estas pessoas poderiam estar contribuindo com o debate.

Comment: Votos no meta são diferentes. Aqui, votos positivos significam que as pessoas concordam com você, e esses 3 downvotes signficam que essas 3 pessoas não concordam com sua sugestão.

Comment: Eu sei disso, foi apenas um exemplo. E isso também ocorre no site normal.

Comment: [Eu prefiro uma ferramenta que avise o usuário que votou "negativamente" e "positivamente" em uma postagem saber se houve edição, seria um meio da pessoa poder saber se o voto dela é justificado para edição, se não remove o voto (sendo down ou up) ou muda (de down para up ou vice-versa).](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4127/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento gostei da sua sugestão. Com certeza ajudaria.

Answer (score 6):

Só para constar, a tal sugestão de comentário já existe, como explicado em:

- [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/198279)

Ou seja a pessoa pode comentar ou "pular/ignorar", para usuários com 2k+ não é mais exibido tal mensagem pois o sistema já considera que o usuário tem experiencia o suficiente.

É algo +ou- assim (no nosso site esta em português):

[image: inserir a descrição do link aqui]

A minha sugestão ainda seria o usuário que deu downvote tanto quanto upvote ser notificado quando houver edições em uma postagem para ele poder considerar se o seu voto ali ainda é correto ou se precisa ser mudado (sendo upvote ou downvote), como disse em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4127/3635