# Usar o próprio texto de sinalização como comentário

Tags: debate, voto-contra, sinalização, novos-usuários

Tentando oferecer mais informações para que novos usuários tenham ao menos ideia sobre o que precisam melhorar em suas postagens, [postei como comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295423/d%c3%bavida-de-produtividade-atalhos#comment600241_295423) o próprio texto da sinalização que fiz na [sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295423/d%C3%BAvida-de-produtividade) (e também rebaixei).

Entendendo que o meu julgamento da sobre a questão não necessariamente reflete o julgamento dos outros *'downvoters' / 'flaggers'* e também que a minha sinalização pode não ser procedente segundo a avaliação dos revisores (O mesmo pensamento se aplica a qualquer outro comentário).

Já fiz isso outras vezes, até para usuários que não pareciam iniciantes. Mas agora me surgiu a dúvida.

Há algo que desabone essa conduta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acredito que não. Na verdade acho que o *engine* deveria fazer isto. E ter mensagens mais significativas.

Mas sempre pode ter alguém que não goste. Já houve alguns debates e que nunca deixaram claro se é bom ou não comentar algo. O fato é que sempre pode explodir alguém que gosta de explodir em qualquer ação que você faça e não seja o que a pessoa espera.

Então me parece útil e uma boa iniciativa. Seria ainda mais útil se colocasse algo específico. Mas não estou dizendo que deve fazer, eu não poderia pedir para ninguém fazer algo que dá trabalho sem que ela queira fazer ou esteja sendo paga justamente para fazer isto, então fica a critério de cada um o que postar.

Talvez copiar um porção maior da mensagem que explica o que a pessoa pode fazer em termos gerais para que a pergunta não seja fechada possa ser uma boa, mas novamente se achar adequado e não um fardo. Isto é só uma dica se não pensou nisso, não é um pedido para fazer.

Comment: _Ter mensagens mais significativas_ seria uma boa mesmo, mas as possibilidades realmente seriam inúmeras! Quando entendo que a postagem ainda pode ser salva, acho que realmente vale o esforço de incluir algo mais específico, não acho que seja o caso dessa pergunta especificamente. Mas fica a dica para as seguintes =)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza dá uma olhada nessa iniciativa (que não foi para a frente): [Comentários enlatados para situações comuns](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/707/3117)

Comment: @Math Muito bom, pena que não seguiu adiante. Eu sei que nas filas de revisão do SO tem esse recurso dispnível (pelo menos revisão de posts de baixa qualidade). Acho que uma aplicação da idéia poderia ser o negativar um post **opcionalmente** selecionar um desses "comentários enlatados". Uma [discussão sobre incluir motivo do downvote já ocorreu aqui, mas com outra conotação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4126/obrigar-quem-deu-downvote-a-comentar-o-motivo) vou referenciar tudo isso e abrir outra thread como proposta de funcionalidade pra ver o que a galera acha. Obrigado!